# Sorting array only works with some sets and not with others

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, debugging

I wrote this adjusted version of bubble sort. It compares every 2nd and 4th elements and if 2nd is greater than 4th it swaps 3rd and 4th with 1st and 2nd. For example, lets say pair1 is (a[0], a[1]) and pair2 is (a[2],a[3]). It compares a[1] with a[3] and if the **value** of a[1] is greater than **value** of a[3], pair1 becomes (a[2], a[3]) and pair2 becomes (a[0],a[1]). I have tested it with 2 sets and only passes one test. Please help me debug this.

```
#include <iostream>

void ssort(int arr[], int arrSize)       //pass integer array and it's size
{
    int j, k;
    bool flag;
    do
    {
        flag = false;  //Set to false at the start
        for (int i = 0; i<arrSize;i++)
        {
            if (i+3 >=arrSize)
            {
                break;       //If boundary is reached
            }
            else
            {
                if (arr[i+1] > arr[i+3])   //compares the value of 2nd element with 4th element
                {

                    j = arr[i+2];  //j holds 3rd element
                    k = arr[i+3];    //k holds 4th element

                    arr[i+2] = arr[i];   //3rd element is now 1st element
                    arr[i+3] = arr[i+1];    //fourth element is now 2nd element

                    arr[i] = j;    //1st is now 3rd element
                    arr[i+1] = k;  //2nd is now fourth element
                    flag = true;

                }
            }
        }

    }
    while (flag);

}
int main()
{

    int test1[24] = {14, 18, 45, 60, 21 ,24, 14, 18, 45, 60, 21, 24, 11 ,55, 23, 40, 24 ,24, 28, 33 ,48, 65, 45, 47};    //Fails this test


//sorted test1 would be {14,18,14,18,21,24,21,24,24,24,28,33,23,40,45,47,11,55,45,60,45,60,48,65}
//displays {23 18 11 18 14 24 14 24 21 24 21 33 24 40 28 47 45 55 45 60 45 60 48 65}

int test2[10] = {10,15,20,28,4,15, 29,35,14,18};   //Passes this test

//sorted order for test2 would be {10,15,4,15,14,18,20,28,29,35}
//displays {10 15 4 15 14 18 20 28 29 35}

    //First set test
    std::cout <<"Unsorted array 1 \n";
    for (int i: test1)
    {
        std::cout <<i <<" ";  //displays unsorted array
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
    ssort(test1,24);

    std::cout <<"Sorted \n";
    for (int i: test1)
    {
        std::cout <<i <<" ";
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";

    //Second set test
    std::cout <<"Unsorted array 2 \n";
    for (int i: test2)
    {
        std::cout <<i <<" ";  //displays unsorted array
    }
    std::cout <<"\n";
    ssort(test2,10);

    std::cout <<"Sorted \n";
    for (int i: test2)
    {
        std::cout <<i <<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about the algorithm or the implementation? Why are you swapping items you didn't look at? How does this sort an input of size 3?

Comment: @KennyOstrom each two numbers are treated as pair of number for example in test1 (14, 18) is considered a pair thus moving it without separation. It only sorts 2 at least 2 pairs, if there is only 3 input size the loop breaks. what I am asking is to find possible logic error that is causing the program to work only with smaller sets.

Comment: It doesn't even work with small sets. try { 3, 2, 1 } Wait ... maybe I misunderstand. I thought it was sorting an array of numbers. If (14, 18) is a distinct item, why isn't it a distinct type?

Comment: @KennyOstrom (14,18) was an example form the array test1. It is sorting an array of numbers. The array consist of random numbers. It's not supposed to work with less than 2 pairs(4 number). look at the 2nd sets after sorting. You can see that it is sorted by the 2nd element in ascending order. (10, **15**,4,**15**,14,**18**,20,**28**,29,**35**).

Comment: look at your step size in the for loop

Comment: If that wasn't enough of a hint, consider that the second elements are all in order, as intended. The problem is the pairs aren't preserved. And that's because ... something I already hinted at.

Comment: @KennyOstrom There is no need. I was able to fix it. Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop runs for size/2 -1 and i should be incrementing by 2 each time.